# Angular router get child param from root component

Tags: javascript, angular, router

I have this structure in my `app.component.html`:

```
<app-main-nav></app-main-nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

This is my routes:

```
const routes = [
  {path: "", redirectTo: "home", pathMatch: "full"},
  {
    path: "posts", component: PostsComponent, 
    children: [{
      path: ":id",
      component: PostComponent
    }];
  }
]
```

I am trying to access the **params** from the `PostComponent` page in my `MaiNavComponent` but it throws an error.

```
export class MainNavComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    route.params.subscribe(console.log)
  }
}
```

How can I get the `:id` of the `PostComponent` from the `MainNavComponent`?

I tried to do this:

```
 route.params.subscribe(console.log)
```

Here I get an **empty** object.

And this:

```
 route.firstChild.params.subscribe(console.log)
```

> Cannot read property 'params' of null

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `ActivatedRoute` only available inside components loaded in an outlet (`route-outlet`). In the outer components you can inject the router and use it as follow:

```
export class MainNavComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private router: Router) {}

    ngOnInit() {

        // Fires when the url changes
        this.router.events.subscribe(data => {
            // Only handle final active route
            if (data instanceof NavigationEnd) {

                 // parsedUrl conatins params, queryParams 
                 // and fragments for the active route
                 let parsedUrl = this.router.parseUrl(this.router.url);

                 console.log(parsedUrl);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: No but the params are empty

Answer (score 0):

```js
constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.loadParams();
}

private loadParams(): void {
    this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
        if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
            let activatedRoute = this.activatedRoute.firstChild;
            while (!activatedRoute) {
                activatedRoute = activatedRoute.firstChild;
            }

            const value = activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('parmeter key');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Modified your while loop to `while(activatedRoute.firstChild !== null)` and your code did work for me just fine. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

You have to snapshot to get ID from the URL.Uodate constructor with below

```
constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute) {   
  }
ngOnInit() {
  // (+) converts string 'id' to a number
  let id = +this.route.snapshot.params['id'];


}
```

Comment: That only works from within the route with the params, not from the root component